# Why are some ZLE sequences being remapped to "self-insert"?

Tags: zsh, zle

I've been tinkering with my dotfiles lately, and at some point I lost use of the default `^A` and `^K` keymappings, which I use frequently.

```
bindkey -L | grep '\^[AK] 
# bindkey -R "^A"-"^C" self-insert
# bindkey "^K" self-insert
```

But the man page for `zshzle` clearly states that `^K` and `^A` are mapped by default to `kill-line` and `asf`, as I've come to expect.

I can't find anywhere in any of my initialization files where this would have been remapped! I certainly didn't do it:

```
print /usr/local/ ~/.z^(compdump|sh_history) ~/dotfiles | xargs ag 'bindkey'
# /Users/vercingetorix/.zshrc
# 56:bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char
# 
# /Users/vercingetorix/dotfiles/zsh/zshrc
# 56:bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char
```

That's all I have!

In fact I *know* I didn't do it:

```
zsh -x &> diagnose.log
exit
wc -l diagnose.log
#     3802 diagnose.log
[[ -z $(ag '\^[AK]' diagnose.log) ]] && print 'nothing!'
# nothing!
[[ -z $(ag 'bindkey -[evaM]' diagnose.log) ]] && print 'nothing!'
# nothing!
```

So what gives? What's happening to the default mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

From the `zshzle` man page:

> In addition to these names, either 'emacs' or 'viins' is also linked to the name 'main'.  If one of the VISUAL or EDITOR environment  variables contain  the  string  'vi'  when  the  shell  starts up then it will be 'viins', otherwise it will be 'emacs'.  bindkey's  -e  and  -v  options provide a convenient way to override this default choice.

Lo and behold, I had recently set `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` to "vim". Removing this setting gives me back my key bindings (I guess these are Emacs defaults, but they're also familiar Mac bindings).